# In R print decimal comma instead of decimal point

Tags: r

I am doing statistical analysis in R. I need to paste the results in a report written in French. In French, floating point numbers are written using a decimal comma instead of decimal point.

Manually replacing points by commas is a bit tedious...

1/ How may I have R print all my floating point numbers with a comma separating the integer and decimal parts ?

Many thanks to rmuc8 for having answered very quickly and effectively to this first question:

> options(OutDec= ",")

This will yield e.g.

> 3.14
>
> [1] 3,14

2/ How may I have R's sprintf("%.1f", x) doing the same ?
e.g I'd like

> sprintf("%.2f", 3.14)

to give the character string

> [1] "3,14"

instead of

> [1] "3.14"

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it with `options`

```
options(OutDec= ",")
```

If you want to apply it on an object like a `data.frame`, you can use `format`

```
format(name_of_dataframe, decimal.mark=",")
```