# Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals

Tags: r, format

I'd like to format numbers with both thousands separator and specifying the number of decimals. I know how to do these separately, but not together.

For example, I use `format` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135122/1840471) for the decimals:

```
FormatDecimal <- function(x, k) {
  return(format(round(as.numeric(x), k), nsmall=k))
}
FormatDecimal(1000.64, 1)  # 1000.6
```

And for thousands separator, `formatC`:

```
formatC(1000.64, big.mark=",")  # 1,001
```

These don't play nicely together though:

```
formatC(FormatDecimal(1000.64, 1), big.mark=",")  
# 1000.6, since no longer numeric
formatC(round(as.numeric(1000.64), 1), nsmall=1, big.mark=",")
# Error: unused argument (nsmall=1)
```

How can I get `1,000.6`?

Edit: This differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299404/in-r-print-decimal-comma-instead-of-decimal-point) which asks about formatting 3.14 as 3,14 (was flagged as possible dup).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`format` not `formatC`:

```
format(round(as.numeric(1000.64), 1), nsmall=1, big.mark=",")  # 1,000.6
```

Answer (score 28):

```
formatC(1000.64, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=1)
```

(sorry if i'm missing something.)

Answer (score 14):

The `scales` package has a `label_comma` function:

```
scales::label_comma(accuracy = .1)(1000.64)
[1] "1,000.6"
```

With additional arguments if you want to use something other than a comma in the thousands place or another character instead of a decimal point, etc (see below).

Note: the output of `label_comma(...)` is a *function* to make it easier to use in `ggplot2` arguments, hence the additional parentheses notation. This could be helpful if you're using the same format repeatedly:

```
my_comma <- scales::label_comma(accuracy = .1, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")

my_comma(1000.64)
[1] "1.000,6"

my_comma(c(1000.64, 1234.56))
[1] "1.000,6" "1.234,6"
```

Answer (score 8):

[`formattable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/index.html) provides `comma`:

```
library(formattable)

comma(1000.64, digits = 1) # 1,000.6
```

`comma` provides an elementary interface to `formatC`.

Comment: The cool thing about formattable, the type remains `numeric`!

Answer (score 0):

Working with [datatable](https://rstudio.github.io/DT)s you can use `DT::formatRound()` (The data type will remain numeric):

```r
DT::datatable(
  data.frame(value = 1000.64),
  rownames = FALSE
) |>
  DT::formatRound(1, digits = 1)
```

*NOTE This answer is a bit beyond the scope of the OP's question, but when working with datatables tables it's the way to go.*