# Convert number with both comma thousands separator in r

Tags: r, formatting

Suppose I have

```
 a = c("88", "haha", NA, "8,888", "2.4k")
```

I want to reformat the numbers to

```
 88, NA, NA, 8888, 24000
```

I read a post about formatting, but still do not understand how to do this..
[Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)

Comment: Not exactly the same but worth mention is John Fox's work in R News from 10 years ago: pages 51-53 of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2005-1.pdf

Comment: If you want an out-of-the-box solution, you can also check out the `readr` package, which has `parse_number` function which can handle currencies as well as the comma separator, but it doesn't handle the `2.4k` case...

Comment: @TheTime Thanks! and I think it should be 'e3' in the sub instead of 'e4'?