# Arsenal summary stats include thousand separator

Tags: r, formatting, numbers, separator

i have the following dummy data.frame for which I'd like to create a summary using tableby

```
require(arsenal)

set.seed(12345)
df<-data.frame(var1=floor(runif(10,1000000,5000000)), var2=floor(runif(10,2500000,1000000000)), group=rep(c("A","B"),5))
desTab<-tableby(group~., data = df)
summary(desTab, digits = 0)
```

The output does not include any separators for the thousands ( "," ). This makes it rather unreadable.

How can I change it?

I played with

```
tableby.control()
```

But with no success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: R does not do that. If you write `3.000` that means `3`. You can add commas (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)), i.e. `3,000` but then this will make them strings. So maybe you can use scientific notation, i.e. 3000000 = 3x10^6...

Comment: Sorry, I meant "," as a separator. Its corrected in the question

Comment: So you don't mind If they are converted to strings?

Comment: No. if its only for the table output