# R date not showed properly in tableOutput (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have this piece of code to show some chart + last row from table, but date not showed properly in tableOutput, Any idea please ?

Last row is this

```
"date","confirmed","diff"
2020-11-19,56898415,650433
```

but shows this
`18585.00 56898415.00 650433.00`

Here is full code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Confirmed Cases"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  position='right',
                  sidebarPanel(
                  tableOutput("table1")
                    
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                  
                plotlyOutput("distPlot")
                  ))
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- read_csv("confirmed_all.csv")
  
  data_last <- tail(data,1)
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable(data_last)
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
    ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
      geom_line(colour = "grey", aes(date, confirmed)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(labels = comma))
    
  })
  
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Link to my new project
http://webcovid19.online/

...
OK, looks that R is showing date in numeric output from 1970 (Posix date), but how to convert it back ? My current code looks lhis
`data_last <- tail(data[ , c("date", "confirmed")],1)` to show only specified column

Here is small dataset

```
"date","confirmed","diff"
2020-01-27,2927,809
2020-01-28,5578,2651
2020-01-29,6167,589
2020-01-30,8235,2068
```

Comment: Would be good to include a small dataset for `data` variable, because we do not have the csv file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `kableExtra` package:

```
data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", "2020-01-20"),
                   confirmed = c(2927, 5578, 6167, 8253),
                   diff = c(809, 2651, 589, 2068))

data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$date)

library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Confirmed Cases"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        position='right',
        sidebarPanel(
            tableOutput("table1")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("distPlot")
        ))
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    data_last <- tail(data, 1)
    
    output$table1 <- function() {
        data_last %>% 
            knitr::kable(format = "html", row.names = FALSE) %>% 
            kable_styling()
    }
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: OK, your option works with renderDataTable (as.Date), but how to implement in my universal scenario when I read data from csv file ? also  the output from Datatable is uselessly difficult with next page buttons... etc, I just want simple table like in TableOutput, Any idea please ?  I updated my Q with dataframe exaple.

Comment: ...I just wanna show properly  last row from my dataframe csv in simple table

Comment: I've updated the answer for better formatting, and removing the row name from the table. To read from the .csv file, just substitute your call to the .csv file back in (i.e., . `data <- read_csv("confirmed_all.csv")`.

Comment: Thanks  Eric, now is working fine, last question : how change number formatting ?  Here is current output > Confirmed 58143122,
I would like to have comma separated like 58,143,122

Comment: Probably bring up a new issue for that, or search stack overflow. [Here is a starting point:](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-format-a-variable-with-commas-now-that-scales-has-changed/56311)

Comment: Hi Eric, I used this template also for showing last increase numbers...How can I add "+"  sign before value ?  like  "+ 3,565"

Comment: @Andrew  You can use `paste0`. For example `x <- 3565`, `y <- paste0("+", x)`. Then display `y` in the table. This can be a new column in your data frame so easy to put in the table. See this post to format with the commas for thousands separator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals

Comment: Bravo, Thanks Eric :)

Comment: I just realized that after this change I lost my decimal comma  separation output due to numeric was changed to character  `    knitr::kable(format = "html", row.names = FALSE, align='l',col.names = c("daily increase from last day"),  ) %>% 
      kable_styling(font_size = 20)`

Comment: Hi Eric, Do you have any idea how fix both issues ? ( comma separation digits and paste0 "+" sign in kable output ) Looks that not possible merge both.

Comment: Yeah, once you add the '+' sign, its a character vector and your comma isn't going to work. You could write your own function to accept a character vector and add commas to to it. I.e. you will send the function the character vector "+12345678" and it returns "+12,345,678". Good programming exercise!