# Is there a possibility to set a default format for the amount of decimals and thousand separator in R for an entire script?

Tags: r, format, decimal, default, separator

I'm trying to format the numbers in graphs and tables, but there are a lot of them. Therefore I am wondering if there is a function or possibility to set a default number of decimals and a default thousand separator for the entire script?

Comment: Does R even do thousands-separators? I'd think only table-rendering functions (`knitr`, `formattable`, `kableExtra`, etc) would provide that functionality. For that option, look into whatever package you're using for table rendering and figure out how it's doing it. (Note: thousands-separators is not a `numeric` thing in R, it is only a *rendering* thing, which means you need to be a bit explicit about doing it. Once you add commas, R will only think of it as a string.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `comma`from `formattable` package.

```
library(formattable)

comma(5000.907, digits = 2) 
# [1] 5,000.91
```

Comment: Please note the _for an entire script_ part of the question. Otherwise, it would be a dupe of [Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals), which also includes your suggestion.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thank you. I was to fast. Should I delete?

Comment: If the graphs and tables have a common structure, you could write a function to do the figure/table generation that includes the formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm gonna try writing a function to help me with the task!