# RStudio - Converting a Numeric to Longitude/Latitude Format

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, numeric

I have a large dataset of 100.000 obersavtions with data for longitude and latitude as well. Some of them are of 6, 7 or 8 digits length without any separation such as a dot. E.g: 12984582 or 8430766. They need to be transformed to 12.984582 and 8.430766. Already tried to solve this problem with gsub/sub but they seem not to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` with `big.mark`. Learned here [Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)

```
# example dataset

x <- 100000:100100
df <- data.frame(x)

format(round(as.numeric(df$x), 1), big.mark=",")
```