# Number Format of labels in Chart

Tags: r, number-formatting

I am looking for a way to format the labels in my piechart in R.
The values are shown with thousands  separator `","` and decimal separator `"."`.
I would like it the other way around, but when I format the value itself, the plot cannot be created, because then my values are characters.

Thanks!
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvrPC.png)

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals) is relevant. Something like `format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")`.

Comment: What plotting library are you intending to use? Default plot? `ggplot`? `plotly`?

Comment: I am using googleVis, but I already tried with plotly and faced the same issues.

format(...) does not work as I explained above: If I format the value, I cannot build a chart, because they are not numbers anymore