# Change a number with comma, which is a char variable, to a numerical

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have some data containing a column named "amount" which look at individual transactions. I have exported a csv file from our database to excel, then uploaded the document into RStudio. When I load the file into my enviroment the "amount" column is formated like (ex. "3021,43"). Instead, I am attempting to make that column to be formatted like 3021.43.

When I use:

```
MD$Belop <- as.numeric(as.character(MD$Belop))
```

All the values containing a comma is returned with NA.
Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number in R with both comma thousands separator and specified decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465941/format-number-in-r-with-both-comma-thousands-separator-and-specified-decimals)

Comment: When importing the data set the `dec` decimal argument to ",".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can swap the comma for a dot:

```r
x <- "3021,43"
num <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x, fixed=TRUE))
num

[1] 3021.43
```