# How to set consistent decimal separators in R data frame?

Tags: r, gsub, separator, decimal-point

Some columns in my data frame have ',' and some have '.' as decimal separator.

```
DateTime             a    b    c
2000-01-01 00:30:00  3,4  6,1  9.5
2000-01-01 00:45:00  3,5  6,8  7.4
```

I would like to have '.' as a decimal separator throughout my data frame.

I have tried

```
df = gsub(',','.',df)
```

but it just gives me a new `Value` instead of a data frame. I also tried

```
df = lapply(df, function(x) as.character(gsub(",",".",df)))
```

but it just makes a list.

I have tried to set the columns as numeric (currently they're all characters due to earlier procedures), but it sets all values in a and b as NA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In R print decimal comma instead of decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299404/in-r-print-decimal-comma-instead-of-decimal-point)

Comment: I snagged this from another answer. `options(OutDec= ".")`. Run this either in a script or console and it should print decimals with a period.

Comment: I tried is as `df %>% options(OutDec=".")` but it gives me the error message `Error in options(., OutDec = ".") : invalid argument`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `,` with `.` in all columns like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace(., ",", ".")))
```

If you have columns where `,` should not be replaced you can address the ones where the change should be implemented more specifically, e.g., like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~str_replace(., ",", ".")))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  DateTime = c(2000-01-01, 2000-01-01),
  a = c("3,4","3.5"),
  b = c("6,1", "6,8"),
  c = c(9.5, 7.4))
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't change anything in the data frame. All `,` and all `.` stay where they are.

Comment: Have you tried with my data? There the solution works. Please post **your** data as a part of the question so we can help you

Comment: Ah, thank you. I tried it with your data. It prints the correct data in the console, but it doesn't change the values in the data frame itself. How can I change that?

Comment: You need to save the result in a new object; for example: `df_NEW <- df %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~str_replace(., ",", ".")))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the numbers with a comma as decimal separator are character strings. Convert them to numeric values like so:

```r
library(readr)
parse_number("3,4", locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))
#> [1] 3.4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>